# Spring Data Rest: Export Non-Data Custom CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I was wondering if it is possible to have SDR generate a REST endpoint for a CrudRepository where T is not a JPA managed entity. Here's my example:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class UserProfile {

    private String id;

    private String username;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String avatarUrl;

    private String email;

}

public class UserRepository implements CrudRepository<UserProfile, String>{
    ...
}
```

The UserRepository class implements all CrudRepository methods partially by making API calls to a different service and partially by loading additional information from a database.

Can I have Spring Data Rest generate a /userprofiles endpoint instead of implementing a RestController myself? So far, I placed UserRepository into a package which is scanned via @EnableJpaRepositories but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Yes if you use a code generator like Jhipster where he generate repo and cruds endpoint for you

Comment: CRUD means create read update and delete. How should this work without JPA?

Comment: Custom implementations of C, U, R and D. Could be using a text file to persist it or just keep it in memory or make calls to a different API.